# Navigation.PushAsync(). When the back arrow is pressed the page seems to be still in memory

Tags: xamarin, events, navigation

I am writing a Xamarin app. In the App.Xaml.cs I expose some events.
I set up a Main Page like this:

```
var nav = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
        MainPage = nav;
```

Then from the Main Page I push another page:

```
void DevicePictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
         Image imse = (Image)sender;
         String NameofDevice =                       
         devicesHandlesDictionary_byDevicepictureID[imse.Id].Name;

         var p = new DevicesPage(NameofDevice);

         Navigation.PushAsync(p);
```

The DevicesPage subscribes to an event (exposed from App).
Setting up some Debug.WriteLine along the code I discovered that DevicesPage is still active when navigate back to MainPage (pressing the back arrow or with Navigation.PopAsync()).
Also when I navigate to DevicesPage again the code is executed twice (Degug.WriteLine string in the Output window appear twice) and 3,4,5 etc. times if I keep going back and forward. It seems like a new page gets created every time and the previous still run in background.
I understand that events should be unsubscribed (in that case where should be done). Also it baffles me that the code still seems to be running in the page navigated back. How to remove the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> DevicesPage is still active when navigate back to MainPage

Just because you navigate away from a page doesn't mean you're done with it.  You may want to re-use it later.  You can explicitly clean up it's resources if you need to (for instance, unsubscribe your event handlers in OnDisappearing) but this doesn't happen automatically

> It seems like a new page gets created every time

it does, because you are **explicitly creating a new instance** of `DevicesPage` each time

```
var p = new DevicesPage(NameofDevice);
Navigation.PushAsync(p);
```

there is nothing preventing you from keeping a reference to a `DevicesPage` instance and re-using it instead of always creating a new one

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for the clarification. It all makes sense. I have already started to unsubscribe OnDisappearing(). I have been following Xamarin tutorial for Navigation and they all instruct to create a new instance. Can you show me how to keep reference of the DevicesPage instead of creating a new one every time? Also NameOfDevice changes all the time, perhaps should I change the structure and pass NameOfDevice in some other way? Again, thanks for the help.

Comment: NameOfDevice changes all the time and that affects the page layout (each "device" has its own controls).

Comment: to reuse an instance,  just store a reference in a class level variable instead of a locally scoped var

Comment: Thanks Jason. I had figured out this. I am gonna create a Dictionary of pages (with name of device as key) that fills as different DevicesPage get created and reuse them if are already loaded. Just for information, is it possible to totally remove a Page from the memory anyway, or is this internal Xamarin business?